# Railo Tomcat 404 redirects and CGI vars

Tags: tomcat, cgi, http-status-code-404, railo

I've run into an issue with 404 redirects on Ubuntu - Railo - Tomcat  (no Apache).

I have the site's /WEB-INF/web.xml redirecting 404 errors to a custom 404.cfm which tries to read and act on certain CGI variables.  The problem is that I'm not getting all the CGI variables, most are null.  The QUERY_STRING is the only variable passed from the missing template.  The rest are either null or for the 404.cfm.

What I want is the template path and query string of the missing template.

Here are some of the cfdumps I've tried:

```
<cfdump var="#cgi#">
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest()#"><!--- returns HTTPServletRequestWrap class, fields, methods --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest()#"><!--- returns ApplicationHttpRequest class, fields, methods --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getAttributeNames()#"><!--- returns apparently useable strings --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getAttribute("query_string")#"><!--- returns Empty:null --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getParameterNames()#"><!--- returns "id" --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getHeaderNames()#"><!--- returns apparently useable strings --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getQueryString()#"><!--- returns original template's query string Yay! --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getRequestURL()#"><!--- returns URL for 404.cfm --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getAttribute("Referer")#"><!--- returns Empty:null --->
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getOriginalRequest().getAttribute("Redirect_URL")#"><!--- returns Empty:null --->
```

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.  Remember, Tomcat is the web server without Apache.

Answer (score 1):

What you should probably do is not use Tomcat for the 404 redirect.  You are correct, I could not get it to get the originally requested path.  This is likely by design.

Instead set the 404 handler in the Railo server administrator to your CFM file.  You will then see the actual requested page.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm wondering if my tuckey urlrewrite filter is bypassing the errors and throwing everything over to index.cfm.
Does this make sense?

I have added the custom 404.cfm to Railo Web Admin and commented the error page out my web.xml.

Comment: Yes, Adam's suggestions work!
1. Use Railo admin for custom 404
2. Move custom 404 template to its own directory
3. adjust tuckey urlrewrite.xml to allow that error directory

Now any nonexistent .CFM request to the root level redirects to index.cfm (Mura site).  I wish it to go to the custom 404 page.

The questions now are:
1. Is the best way to resolve this with reg ex in the urlrewrite filter?
2. If so, what's the reg ex?  I want to allow all root level pages (*.cfm + *.html)  except index.cfm to pass so they fall into the 404.
3. Is this logic correct?  If not where should the reg ex go?